# Thunderbid extension: open eml file

Tags: javascript, xul, thunderbird, thunderbird-addon

I already created an extension that does the following:

When I run Thinderbird with the command line `thunderbird -MyCustomParam1 "12345"` my extension will open a compose window and add the parameter `"12345"` to the window.

Some code that I use:

```js
// In the calling code
var args = {
  param1: 12345,

};

args.wrappedJSObject = args;
var watcher = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/embedcomp/window-watcher;1"]
                            .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIWindowWatcher);
watcher.openWindow(null, url, windowName, features, args);


// In the window code
var args = window.arguments[0].wrappedJSObject;
```

Of course using the correct url and features.

Now I want to do the same, but for the message window and with am `eml` file that is choose.

You can open an `eml` file from the command line like this: `Thunderbird test.eml` (this will open the mail in a new window).

What I want is the following:

`Thunderbird test.eml -MycustomParam1 "1234"` should open the mail, and add the param `"1234"` to screen, so I can access it in the document window, just like example 1.

So basically I want something like `watcher.openWindow`, but with a given `eml` file.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see how this is done in the [`MsgOpenFromFile` function](http://hg.mozilla.org/comm-central/file/f7a0c097c849/mail/base/content/mailWindowOverlay.js#l1851), it is being called for the File / Open Saved Message menu item. You basically have to take the `eml` file ([get an nsIFile instance from file path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_code_modules/FileUtils.jsm#The_File_constructor)), [turn it into a URI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIIOService#newFileURI%28%29) and then change the query string before opening a message window:

```js
uri.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIURL);
uri.query = "type=application/x-message-display";
watcher.openWindow(null, "chrome://messenger/content/messageWindow.xul", "_blank",
                   "all,chrome,dialog=no,status,toolbar", uri);
```

Comment: This works fine. But when i a have html mail, it prints the mail as plain text. Is there a way to specify that its a HTML mail when opening a file?

Comment: Answer for the question in the above comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27689496/opening-and-printing-a-thunderbird-html-file/27690687#27690687