# Thunderbird extension: open EML file as draft

Tags: javascript, xul, thunderbird, thunderbird-addon

After my [first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984796/thunderbid-extension-open-eml-file) here, I am now looking for a way do the the same, but instead of opening an EML as a message, I want to open it as a draft.

Basically, I want to load a generated EML file into the compose window, so I can directly send it.

I already found some code, but I can't find the correct documentation on how to use it

```
var filePath = new FileUtils.File(getPath(params));           
var uri = io.newFileURI(filePath);  

var msgComposeService = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/messengercompose;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIMsgComposeService);
var  messenger = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/messenger;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIMessenger);

var hdr = messenger.msgHdrFromURI(uri.spec);
var identity = getIdentityForHeader(hdr, Components.interfaces.nsIMsgCompType.Draft);
var msgWindow = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/messenger/msgwindow;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIMsgWindow);
msgComposeService.OpenComposeWindow(null,null,uri,Components.interfaces.nsIMsgCompType.Draft,Components.interfaces.nsIMsgCompFormat.Default,identity,msgWindow);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest injecting the eml file into a local Drafts folder so as to get an nsIMsgDBHdr, and then calling the `ComposeMessage` function with `Ci.nsIMsgCompType.Draft, Ci.nsIMsgCompFormat.Default, yourMsgHdr.folder, yourMsgHdr'sURI`.

I think there are several StackOverflow answers on how to inject a given message into a folder.

Comment: And how do you inject a given message into a folder? i cant seem to find an answer on stackoverflow.